# objective c - table view not able to show the data in the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, tableview

I have an array of data. And wr my data are not displaying in the screen. Not sure, what i am missing.

```
@property NSMutableArray *NotifTotal;

@interface HomeVC ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@end

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.NotifTotal count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FilterTableViewCell";
    FilterTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    NSDictionary *dict;
    dict = [self.NotifTotal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", dict);  // data is coming.
    NSString* salt = [dict objectForKey:@"salt"];
    NSString* name = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"%@%@", name,swerk); // in console i can print the data
    cell.sLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", salt];
    cell.nLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", name];
    return cell;
}
```

Why my data is not showing in my screen.I added the delegate, data source also in my screen.Any solution ?

Comment: Have you binded the delegates and datasource properly? Pls recheck.

Comment: yes, i did for table view

Comment: My guess is the array is empty, or nil.  A simple test would be `NSLog(@"count is %d", self.NotifTotal.count);` in numberOfRows, and  `NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);` in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  You should see a > 0 count and as many index paths as visible cells.

Answer (score 1):

You said "I added the delegate, data source also in my screen" but it is not very clear to me by that you meant conforming your `HomeVC` to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` as your posted code or you actually set the delegate of your UITableView to `HomeVC`. So here are something you should check:

- Set datasource of your UITableView to `HomeVC` using Interface Builder or following code:

  ```
  self.tableView.dataSource = self; // I am assuming self == HomeVC instance
  ```
- Make sure `[self.NotifTotal count] > 0`.
- Make sure it is not about UITableView's configuration issue by adding a break point to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and confirm it called.

  - If it isn't: go back to 2 points above.
  - If it is: this is UI issue, let's check if your cells's height is near 0 or they have a transparent color and so on. You can use Xcode's View Debugging tool to debug the issue.

Comment: i printed like `cell.textLable.text = @"data";`. Now its  printing.

Comment: You meant that when you set `cell.textLable.text = @"data";`, it shows up on your screen? if so let's check if `sLabel` and `nLabel` are nil.
 - If they are nil: make sure these variables connected to your cell's labels via IBOutlet.
 - If they are not nil: debug their frame after the cell is fully loaded then make sure their position are vitiable in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned having registered the cell identifier yet, I assume that's the problem.  One way to do this is in your storyboard or xib.  Select the prototype cell in your tableview, and set the "identifier" field (in the Attributes inspector pane of Interface Builder).  Set it to "FilterTableViewCell".

[image: identifier field for a prototype cell]

Comment: i already have that. I mentioned that already. Since i can see the table view, with cell bg color. But not able to see onl data

Comment: @david Verify that sLabel and nLabel are not nil, during tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.   Also, you didn't show us the code where you populated NotifTotal.  Verify the strings you're setting sLabel and nLabel to are what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a xib problem. I added a bit of code in the middle.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FilterTableViewCell";
FilterTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//Add this part
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FilterTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
//end


NSDictionary *dict;
dict = [self.NotifTotal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);  // data is coming.
NSString* salt = [dict objectForKey:@"salt"];
NSString* name = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
NSLog(@"%@%@", name,swerk); // in console i can print the data
cell.sLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", salt];
cell.nLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", name];
return cell;
}
```